# Facebook Graph API | Request [400] Errorr

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, facebook-sdk-4.0

I create a bot to monitor the comment if there is any new comment and if so it will automatically [private_replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/private-replies/) them But instead i got a Request [400] Error instead.

```
def monitor_comment():
    print("Bot is monitoring comments")
    time.sleep(5)
    comment_data = graph.get_connections(COMBINED_POST_ID_TO_MONITOR,"comments",order='reverse_chronological')
    commends = []
    for comment in comment_data['data'][:10]:
        commends.append (comment)
    data = commends[0]['id']
    data_converted = str(data)
    #time.sleep(5)
    print(data)
    return data_converted
def private_reply(comment_ids):
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/messages?"
    access = {"access_token":Page_Token}
    params = {
"recipient": {
    "comment_id": comment_ids
},
"message": {
    "text":"Testing Private_Replies"
}
    request = requests.post(url=url, files=access, json=params)
    print(request)
```

**This is the logs**

> {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"AMCiqy1Aw8CyODPlUBE1b98"}}

Comment: Can you try getting the text of the response? `request.text`. See what the 400 error message tells you.

Comment: 400 is a general purpose error that means the request was incorrect in some way.  As a guess, what is `comment_id` supposed to be?  The name implies it's supposed to be a single value, but you appear to be sending a list of values.

Comment: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"AMCiqy1Aw8CyODPlUBE1b98"}} My Token is permenatent  and it a Page_Access_Token. I don't know why i got this error.

Comment: @JohnGordon The value of comment_id is a single Value

Comment: Are you really supposed to use the `files=` parameter to pass the token?  Usually that sort of thing goes in a header.

Comment: I try to create https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/messages?access_token=Page_Token + params

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message? `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user`

Comment: I think i know why because by using access = "access_token", it did not take the token but if i use this instead url = https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/messages?access_token=Page_Token. I no longer have that error now i seem to be getting error about Permission {"error":{"message":"(#10903) This user cant reply to this activity","type":"OAuthException"